# Unfortunately the app stopped Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Here is the code. It doesn't give any error in console. I have made another activity class test_me.java. When I click on the dialog option, it gives the error that " Unfortunately the app stopped working". Please tell me what is the problem here.

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    Context context=this;
    Intent testIntent;
        Intent progIntent;
        Intent settingIntent;
        Intent resultIntent; public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);  
            Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);        
            b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
                  if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
                  {                   final CharSequence[] items = {"Test", "ProgMode", "Settings","Result"};
                     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Menu Options")
                  .setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                             if(items[item]=="Test")
                            {testIntent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, test_me.class);
                                startActivity(testIntent);
                                }
                             else if(items[item]=="ProgMode")
                                {progIntent = new Intent(TestActivity.this,prog_mode.class);
                                startActivity(progIntent);

                                    }
                             else if(items[item]=="Settings")
                                {settingIntent = new Intent(TestActivity.this,setting_mode.class);
                                startActivity(settingIntent);
                                                                }
                             else if(items[item]=="Results")
                                {
                                 resultIntent = new Intent(TestActivity.this,result_mode.class);
                                startActivity(resultIntent);
                                                                }

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                     });
                      builder.setPositiveButton("Back",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
}
```

Here is the Log

```
06-07 17:44:15.598: I/dalvikvm(654): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-07 17:44:15.978: I/dalvikvm(654): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 17:44:16.088: I/dalvikvm(654): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-07 17:44:16.148: I/dalvikvm(654): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 17:44:16.538: D/android.widget.GridLayout(654): vertical constraints: y3 - y0 > 637, y1 - y0 > 129, y2 - y1 > 135, y3 - y0 < 618 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y3 - y0 < 618. 
06-07 17:44:16.608: I/dalvikvm(654): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-07 17:44:16.638: I/dalvikvm(654): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 17:44:16.858: D/gralloc_goldfish(654): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-07 17:44:17.108: I/dalvikvm(654): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-07 17:44:17.139: I/dalvikvm(654): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 17:44:21.638: D/AndroidRuntime(654): Shutting down VM
06-07 17:44:21.638: W/dalvikvm(654): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {achira.test/achira.test.test_me}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at achira.test.AchActivity$1$1.onClick(AchActivity.java:84)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-07 17:44:21.688: E/AndroidRuntime(654):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 17:44:22.349: I/dalvikvm(654): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
06-07 17:44:22.388: I/dalvikvm(654): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
06-07 17:44:24.118: I/Process(654): Sending signal. PID: 654 SIG: 9
```

Comment: *Unfortunately the app stopped working* is the error log you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this

```
Context context=TestActivity.this;
```

should come inside onCreate

also dismiss your dialog

reset your adb or restart your emulator you will get errors in logcat

your logcat says

```
E/AndroidRuntime(654): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {achira.test/achira.test.test_me}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

that means you haven't declared your activities in manifest

declare activity like this inside application tag

```
<activity
            android:name=".test_me"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

Comment: this is written in your log cat 'have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?' so have you really declared your activity i.e the activities which your calling in manifest file?

Comment: I created the activity manually. I haven't declared in manifest. How do i do that?

Comment: yeah i have. The code there is correct and running if I run it under a separate project too.

Comment: what do you mean by separate project? Activities shoul be present in the project you are running and also should be declared in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with a similar kind of issue. If you are creating a context variable use it every where. do not write getApplicationContext() even for a toast. And Change the context variable like this inside oncreate(){}

```
context = TestActivity.this; //pass activity context.
```

declare context as a class level variable

Answer (score 0):

You are not dismissing the dialog after pressing singleChoiceButton. Call `dialog.cancel()` after each `startActivity()` statement which are inside `onClick` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Just comment or remove this statement...

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 Changes in your code.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Change to

```
Toast.makeText(TestActivity .this, items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
```

Change to

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity .this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class test_me.java to your manifest,it should work afterwards.